# Submit post form from remote URL

Tags: php, html, forms, post, curl

I have two sites, both sites have the same form:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <p><label for="u_name">Username: </label><input type="text" name="u_name" value=""></p>

    <p><label for="u_pass">Password: </label><input type="password" name="u_pass" value=""></p>

    <p><button type="submit" name="go">login</button></p>
</form>
```

The form on site 2 goes to a secret page, but i need the form on site 1 to go to that same secret page on site 2s server.

How can i pass on the post form data from site 1 to site 2 and thus skip the site 2 log in page?

Comment: Why can't you just add the 2nd site's url to the *action* parameter?

Comment: @Andrius Yeah, a single parameter which make fix ;)

Comment: If the client has to access it there is no such thing as a "secret page".

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="http://site2.com/login">
```

This is bad practice though, see [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).